# Sending a GET request through a REST API in Java with multiple inputs

Tags: java, rest, input, parameters, get

I need to send a request using Java to an existing REST service using GET with multiple input parameters.

If the initial url for the calculation I want is:
    `https://api.restservice123.com/api/calculate`

I want to make a calc object e with the following parameters:

```
calcObj e = new calcObj();

e.token="token_ABC123";
e.country="US";
e.amount = 100;
e.price = 24;
e.customer = "bob";
```

the url should look something like this:

`https://api.restservice123.com/api/calculate?token=token_ABC123&country=US&amount=100&price=24&customer=bob`

Is there any framework that will combine the parameters from the calc object and reformat them into the url appropirate format and combine them with the api url?

I ended up making a method in the calc object that puts all the non null parameters into a list of strings and combines them using a Joiner from google common and connecting to the url using an HttpURLConnection. But this method looks bad as I'm hoping there's something out there that can already do all of this much more elegantly, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The [URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) class works well for this. It has a method [setParameters(java.util.List)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#setParameters(java.util.List)) that takes a list of name value pairs and builds a URI from them.

Comment: Seems like this only accepts lists of namevaluepair type, and I couldn't find an easy way to extract a list like this from an object. I ended up converting the object into a beanmap and putting all the non-null values into an list and joining them on "&". This is ugly but fairly versatile.